# Warning about writing .cls files in texpad

Tags: document-classes, mac, mactex, filesystem-access, texpad

I'm using texpad to typeset my documents. Everytime texpad compiles a document, a popup warning about denied writing permissions on the .cls file appears.
Since I'm new to LaTeX, I do not know how does the typeset pipeline works, so I think that the typesetter is trying to write the installed class although it is not necessary.

How to fix it?

UPDATE

Minimal working example causing the problem

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\title{Una revisión a la extracción automatizada de\\* 
reglas de negocio }

\maketitle

\section{Introducción}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{estado_arte_v_1_ref}  

\end{document}
```

[image: Structure of my project]

Comment: Are you literally editing a .cls when you write your documents, or are you just using one via a `\documentclass` command?

Comment: @MikeRenfro I'm using the `\documentclass` command but it seems that texpad or LaTeX or any other software is trying to modify it. In fact, texpad outline shows that all my document is hanging from the .cls document.

Comment: Not a Texpad user (and won't be near a Mac for most of the day), but the screenshots I saw of their outline view always had a .tex file at the root, and never a .cls. And [their user guide section about the organizer](https://www.texpadapp.com/support/osx#organiser) shows options to create a new file or open an old one on startup. If you start a new .tex document from there, does the problem go away?

Comment: @MikeRenfro ahhhm you are right the root file is a .tex. But the next big leaf is the .cls file. I've added a new screenshot with my project structure

Comment: But your Introduction section is defined in your .tex file, and not in the .cls? Can you cut your .tex file down small enough to post here as a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @MikeRenfro I've added the MWE as you asked. I copied the class to the root directory of the project and the problem disappeared. I think that, given my solution, this is not worth of your time (or mine) by now since everything is working not as perfectly as it should but good enough to be usable.

Comment: I don't have `sig-alternate.cls` is this available somewhere? (I do have a `sig-alternate` file for TeX4ht so clearly it is not unheard of.)

Comment: Did you name your `.tex` file the same way as the class file, so that texpad gets confused?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer nop. The file has a different name.

Comment: @cfr The file is a class used to generate ACM articles. You can download it from http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate-v1.1

Comment: @JPCF Thanks. You should add that information to your question since the class is not in the standard distributions or on CTAN.